# php curl_exec returns "HTTP/1.1 100 Continue" followed by "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to convert the below curl command which gives me JSON response to PHP curl code.

`curl -X POST --tls-max 1.2 --insecure https://xxxxxxxxx.com/getkey --cert client.crt --key client.key --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"param1\": \"value1\", \"param2\": \"value2\"}"`

My PHP code is,

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://xxxxxxx.com/getkey");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, "/var/www/html/certs/client.crt");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, "/var/www/html/certs/client.key");
 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$header = array('Content-Type: application/json');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

return $result;
```

When I run this PHP code I am getting below error.

```
* About to connect() to xxxxxxx.com port 443 (#1)
*   Trying xx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
* Connected to xxxxxxx.com (xx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 443 (#1)
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=*.xxxxx.com,O="xxxxxxxxxx.",L=xxxxxxxx,ST=xxxxxx,C=US
*       start date: Nov 10 00:00:00 2021 GMT
*       expire date: Nov 10 23:59:59 2022 GMT
*       common name: *.xxxxx.com
*       issuer: CN=DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US
> POST /getkey HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxxxxx.com
Accept: */* 
Content-Length: 272
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: application/json; boundary=----------------------------d7326044efb7

* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* NSS: client certificate from file
*       subject: CN=XXX-Dev-Client
*       start date: Sep 09 04:00:00 2020 GMT
*       expire date: Sep 09 04:00:00 2040 GMT
*       common name: XXX-Dev-Client
*       issuer: CN=CARoot-XXX-Dev
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Connection: Close
< Content-Type: application/json
<
* Closing connection 1
```

What is the setting I am missing to get the 100 and then 404 codes.

Note:
When I execute the curl command using shell_exec() I am getting the json response, but when I use only PHP curl I am getting the mentioned error.

Comment: The 100 is irrelevant, just "Ok so far". The problem is the 404. The response body might contain more information, but otherwise check that the URL is correct and refer to the provider's documentation.

Comment: Thanks @Sammitch. The issue is resolved. I have added the root cause of this issue and the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to disable sending `Expect: 100-continue`:

```
$header = array('Expect:', 'Content-Type: application/json');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
```

The same for curl for test purposes

```
curl -X POST --tls-max 1.2 --insecure https://xxxxxxxxx.com/getkey --cert client.crt --key client.key -H "Expect:" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"param1\": \"value1\", \"param2\": \"value2\"}"
```

You seem to post JSON incorrectly. The correct post data

```
$payload = json_encode($data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried your suggestion, it didn't give me the 100 code, but still throwing 404 error.

`**
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Connection: Close
< Content-Type: application/json
<
 Closing connection 1
**`

NOTE: The curl command works fine even without adding your suggestion.

Comment: I don't see the request and the data. Maybe the $data is invalid.

Comment: The $data is,

$data = array("param1" => "value1", "param2" => "value2");

Comment: See my updates.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I didn't convert the POST data to JSON format. After converting the POST data to JSON format using json_encode it worked and I am able to get the response.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @273K for the solution.

The reason for this error is, I didn't convert the POST data to JSON format. After converting the POST data to JSON format using json_encode it worked and I am able to get the response from the URL.